# Magento Vagrant installation does not generate classes

Tags: magento2, dependency-injection, setup-di-compile

I have switched to windows for a new project, and just setup Magento 2 using this vagrant box: https://github.com/paliarush/magento2-vagrant-for-developers

I have it working, it is displaying frontend + backend in developer mode. (although very slow)
Now, when I set it to production mode and do a setup:di:compile, it looks like it does that without any errors, but the var/di and var/generation folders are not generated. When I add them myself and run the dependency injection, they stay empty.

Anyone has a clue what could cause this?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have permission issues on the var folder. Check your user and group permissions. Also check your vagrantfile to make sure config.vm.synced_folder owner and group are set correctly.

Comment: ls -l var says everybody may read, write and execute. Static content also does not get deployed to the pub/static folder. What did i do wrong haha